# Drupal Image as image with link to a node

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

OK
I've actually spent 3 hours searching for how should I get images correctly on my drupal site so please don't get annoyed with this easy question. (sob...)
I want to upload an image to my front page as a button for redirecting to login page.
How CAN I achieve this?????
I mean how should I store image as in Drupal and how can I get it in the position I want on the page???
I tried creating a content type called image and then created a View of block type but it doesn't seems correct to me.
What is the correct set of steps for storing and handling images in drupal??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a block in your Drupal site and assign it to a region in the front page. Added the Image via PHP code there.